# Pegar Tabela em forma de string

Tags: lua, lua-table

Estou tentando pegar uma tabela em forma de string.
EX:

```
tabela = {1, b=2, {c=3}}
print(getTableString(tabela))
```

Se essa função existisse, e funcionasse, retornaria:

```
-> tabela = {1, b=2, {c=3}}
```

Existe algum modo de fazer isso?

Comment: Eu acho que tem como, mas não é algo tão trivial (mas não complicado). Se eu tiver tempo eu faço alguma coisa mas não prometo. Acho que essencialmente tem que montar este texto na mão. Tem que pegar o nome da variável, pegar os nomes dos elementos e valores existentes na tabela. Não quer dizer que resolveria qualquer situação mas aí já vai complicar. Por exemplo, seria um problema ter a existência de `nil`. Talvez exista alguma outra forma melhor e mais simples, talvez usando algum tipo de introspecção, mas não sei.

Comment: Não entendi o seu problema... O que você quer é pegar uma variável usando seu nome numa string?

Comment: Veja http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization.

Answer (score 1):

Essa função imprime na maneira que você deseja:

```
local function getTableString(t)

    local r = '{'

    for k, v in pairs(t) do
        if type(k) == 'number' then
            k = ''
        else
            k = k .. ' = '
        end
        if r ~= '{' then
            r = r .. ', '
        end
        r = r .. k
        if type(v) == 'table' then
            r = r .. getTableString(v)
        else
            r = r .. tostring(v)
        end
    end 

    r = r .. '}'

    return r

end

tabela = {1, b=2, {c=3}}
print(getTableString(tabela))
```

retornará somente o valor da tabela ex.: `{1, b=2, {c=3}`

Se você quiser retornar como na sua pergunta, **imprimindo** o nome da tabela, há esta opção:

```
local function getTableStringWithName(t)

    local r, n = '{', ''

    if type(t) == 'string' then
        n = ' -> ' .. t .. ' = '
        t = loadstring('return ' .. t)()
    end

    for k, v in pairs(t) do
        if type(k) == 'number' then
            k = ''
        else
            k = k .. ' = '
        end
        if r ~= '{' then
            r = r .. ', '
        end
        r = r .. k
        if type(v) == 'table' then
            r = r .. getTableStringWithName(v)
        else
            r = r .. tostring(v)
        end
    end 

    r = r .. '}'

    return n .. r

end

tabela = {1, b=2, {c=3}}
print(getTableStringWithName('tabela'))
```

Note que a tabela **tem** que ser passada por string, assim é possível obter o nome dela.